# How to visualize H2O Tree?

Tags: python, visualization, decision-tree, h2o

I have df `data_categorical` and a model `model`.
I converted my df to h2o frame with
`data = h2o.H2OFrame(data_categorical)`

and trained my model with

```
model = H2ORandomForestEstimator(ntrees=1, max_depth=20, nfolds=10)
# Train model
model.train(x=training_columns, y=response_column, training_frame=train)
```

I'm trying to visualize the tree that is created (note that I only need one tree) but I can't seem to do that.
I downloaded the mojo file with
`model.download_mojo(path,get_genmodel_jar=True)`
But I don't know what to do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the workflow described in the documentation below:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-genmodel/javadoc/overview-summary.html#viewing-a-mojo

```
java -cp h2o.jar hex.genmodel.tools.PrintMojo --tree 0 -i model.zip -o model.gv -f 20 -d 3
dot -Tpng model.gv -o model.png
open model.png
```

Comment: Does that show the prediction (the final result / ```model.predict()```) or just a single tree?

Comment: Just a single tree (hence the --tree parameter).

Comment: So do I need to call ```predict``` somewhere to get the actual result and then graph it?

Comment: No, it's not visualizing predictions.  It's visualizing a tree of the model.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows/python users I put together a small recipe including links for all steps:

General info:
http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/mojo-quickstart.html

1. install graphViz:
   https://forum.graphviz.org/t/new-simplified-installation-procedure-on-windows/224
2. install java JDK 14:
   https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk14-archive-downloads.html
3. add Java to PATH environment variable (to be able to execute from console)
4. Compile H2O model in python and export model with the .download_mojo(path) function:

`decTreeModel.download_mojo('C:/User/L/mojoExports/myMojoModel.zip')`

5. Go to location of the myMojoModel.zip and start CMD in this directory.In CMD type:

`java -cp h2o.jar hex.genmodel.tools.PrintMojo --tree 0 --levels 21 --title "title for tree" -i myMojoModel.zip -o model.gv -f 20 -d 3`

```
meaning of parameters:

--tree n        : n is the number of the tree to be exported if there are more than one model in the mojo model (e.g. when using cross validation)

--levels n      : n is number of categorical levels to be printed (default 10)

--title "string"    : you can specify the title here

-i "path"       : "path" is path to input model (myMojoModel.zip)

-o "path"       : "path" is path to output graph (model.gv)

-f n            : n is the font size

-d n            : n is the number of decimals displayed for numbers
```

6. in CMD, create the .png with graphViz. Type

`dot -Tpng model.gv -o model.png`

7. it will create a .png in that directory which you can view with any png viewer