# Type error when visualising h2o random-forest model tree

Tags: python, random-forest, h2o

I have built a random-forest model with h2o. I am trying to plot it with h2otree. I am getting a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I can replicate the error. The class [H2OTree](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/_modules/h2o/tree/tree.html#H2OTree) calls a function `__decode_categoricals(model, response['levels'])` which iterates over reponse levels of type None.

```py
from h2o.tree import H2OTree
first_tree = H2OTree(model = rf_model, tree_number = 0, tree_class = target_class_category)
```

```py
#error replication
params = {"model": model.model_id,
                  "tree_number": 0,
                  "tree_class": target_class_category}


response = h2o.api(endpoint="GET /3/Tree", data=params)
for lvl_index in response['levels']:

    if len(lvl_index) >0: #error, 'NoneType' has no len()
        print('yes')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to visualize an H2O Tree you can use the Mojo Visualizer (documentation [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html#viewing-a-mojo-model)) or see previous questions/posts on this:

[How to visualize H2O Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56938966/how-to-visualize-h2o-tree)

[Visualizing H2O GBM and Random Forest MOJO Models Trees in Python](https://dzone.com/articles/visualizing-h2o-gbm-and-random-forest-mojo-models)